# Netbeans giving me an error message but it works as I want it

Tags: java, function, netbeans, return

I have a subclass which contains a function which returns a float. I call that function in a try catch statement, if the an if statement fails and the else catches it I want that function to "crash" by returning noting like this `return;`

Here is that function:

```
float calc(... some arguments ...) {
    ...

    if (operator.equals("+")) number = num1+num2;
    else if (operator.equals("-")) number = num1-num2;
    else if (operator.equals("*")) number = num1*num2;
    else if (operator.equals("/")) number = num1/num2;
    else return; // Here Netbeans gives me an error saying "Missing return value"

    return number;
}
```

Now this function is getting called in a try and I if the else gets executed I want the function to "crash" and go to the catch statement and give the user an error message. This works exactly the way I want it but why does Netbeans give me an error?? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Don't use pseudo code in the method declaration when the problem is about the method declaration...

Comment: I'm  not seeing a return value declared on your method signature. something like `public void calc`?

Comment: Its just float calc(...) and there is a return which returns a value further down the function.

Comment: I edited the code so you can see that I have a functioning return in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you want it to "crash", but you need to indicate an error of some sort.  Because  the method isn't returning `void`, returning nothing is a compiler error.

Instead, throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.

```
else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal operator: " + operator);
```

Just make sure you actually return a valid value at the end:

```
return number;
```

Comment: This worked and was what my programming teacher talked about but she didnt know what type of throw it would be, thank you. I'll accept it in 7 min ;)

Comment: Your teacher doesn't know which type of exception to throw, or is she letting you decide the type of exception as part of your assignment?

Comment: She said it should be a throw but she couldn't remember at that moment how to do it :P

Answer (score 2):

You can't `return;` from this function (return `void`) because that's not how your method is declared. When you declare it as `float calc` you are making a promise that you will **always** return a `float` value.

Further, you're already in a `try-catch` block, so you don't want to return nothing anyway--what you want to do is throw some Exception to catch. Make sure that whatever Exception you throw is appropriate for your particular case. As I don't know anything about what your function does, it's not for me to say what kind of Exception you ought to throw.

```
public float calc(float[] args) throws Exception { // Use a more specific Exception!
    // do stuff
    if (somethingIsWrong) {
        throw new Exception("something is wrong!");
    }
    return number; // Always return a float!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use Exceptions for that.

ex.

if "operator" is one of your arguments use IllegalArgumentException :

```
function calc(... some arguments ...) {
    ...

    if (operator.equals("+")) number = num1+num2;
    else if (operator.equals("-")) number = num1-num2;
    else if (operator.equals("*")) number = num1*num2;
    else if (operator.equals("/")) number = num1/num2;
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

or if your want more specific approach extend RuntimeException, something like 
`MyAppIllegalOperatorException`, and throw/catch one of them